# Sync using event issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program, p1, which initiates 2 threads, t1 and t2.

t1 initiates an event and idly wait for a signal (c++/CLI)

t2 is a COM client, it communicates with COM server,
COM server will open/create a handle of the same event, and send the signal, (c++)

problem is, even COM server send a signal successfully, t1 failed to catch the signal, it just idly waits.

Relevant Code:
t1:

```
String^ eventName1 = "eventName1";
EventWaitHandle^ event1 = gcnew EventWaitHandle(false,EventResetMode::ManualReset, eventName1);
bool tag =  event1->WaitOne(10000,true);  // This never returns..
Log_(tag);
```

COM Server:

```
wchar_t * eventName1 = "eventName1";
HANDLE event1 = CreateEvent(NULL,true,false,eventName1);  // or use event1 = OpenEventW(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE,0,eventName1); makes no diff
SetEvent(event1);
```

Thanks

Comment: It does not return after ten seconds?

Comment: Oh - maybe 'std::wstring' instead of string?

Comment: @Martin it doesnt return after 10s at all. I don't think the string is the problem, it should be more specific to the COM server part, I tested using the same code on T1 and COM client, it has no issue.

Comment: actually it returns, but indicates timed out

Comment: Just a tip: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx This page says you can use Global\ and Local\ prefixes in event names. Please try to prefix the name with Global\ and check out if it works.

Comment: thanks, it seems to work. However, sometimes it tells me I don't have the access for GLOBAL\event1, and sometimes it works.